# Schedule Follow up contracts crm2011

Tags: windows, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm

How can I setup in CRM 2011 a task to send an email or a notification 1 month before expiring a contract . Contracts are expiring without me noticing.
Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a workflow that will be triggered on Creation of contract and wait till your date (contract end date minus 1 month). Recheck following [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11291.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-workflows-wait-and-timeout.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for replying but i have done this but it is not applying to my current contracts . Can you specify please ?

Comment: To apply the same solution for existing contracts you can mark your workflow as On-Demand, select existing contracts and run workflow against existing workflows.